# Colgroup and Col aren't visible on desktop

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have simple table on which I'm trying to add `colgroup` and `col` but they aren't visible. It is also partly break the responsiveness of the table.

On mobile version the red cols are visible but are wrong.

Here is the table

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table td::before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Statement Summary</caption>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2" style="background-color:red; text-align: center;">
    <col style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Account</th>
      <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">04/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
      <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$842</td>
      <td data-label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the Jsfiddle where you can see the responsiveness: https://jsfiddle.net/d5yfteck/

How can I use `colgroup` and `col`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
 table tr {
      background-color: #f8f8f8;
    }
```

is overriding the `colgroup` definitions.

Without that line your code is working fine:
[your code with colgroup](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=bbe8b831-b6d7-4742-8b8b-5c40e5d8ec0e)

**UPDATE:**

If you wish to achieve the same effect on mobile,
in your mobile layout the columns presented as rows so one solution is to use classes in the media tag (`.red` `.yellow`), also see that `tbody` should be set with other color.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but still the mobile version is not okay when I add `<colgroup>` remove the whole `<colgroup>` tags and see how should look like on mobiles

Comment: @Ivanov check the link, I have updated it, that is funny because in mobile you can use your mistake to fix the layout.

Comment: Thank you for your help